# Removing Labels from a Windows Form when it's no longer needed

Tags: c#, forms, label

Say I have this code for a windows form:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
    InitializeComponent();
}

// - This Form1_Shown class is what's done AFTER the form is shown! Put stuff here!
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    methods.WriteTextToScreen("HelloLabel", "Hello!", 15, 15);
    methods.sleepFor(1);
    methods.EraseScreenLabel(Form1.HelloLabel);
    methods.WriteTextToScreen("GoodbyeLabel", "Goodbye!", 80, 80);
    methods.sleepFor(3);
    methods.EraseScreenLabel(Form.GoodbyeLabel);
}

public class methods
{

    public static int timeSlept;

    public static Label[] UsedTextBoxes = new Label[10000000000000000000];

    public static void WriteTextToScreen(string name, string text, int locX, int locY)
    {
        int numberOfPrintedItems = methods.UsedTextBoxes.GetLength(1);
        Label tempLabel = new Label();
        UsedTextBoxes[numberOfPrintedItems + 1] = tempLabel;

        tempLabel.Text = text;
        tempLabel.Name = name;
        tempLabel.Location = new Point(locX, locY);
        tempLabel.Visible = true;
        tempLabel.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void EraseScreenLabel(Label label)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel obj = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        obj.Controls.Remove(label);
        label = null;
    }

    public static void sleepFor(int seconds)
    {
        timeSlept = 0;

        System.Timers.Timer newTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        newTimer.Interval = 1000;
        newTimer.AutoReset = true;

        newTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(newTimer_Elapsed);

        newTimer.Start();

        while (timeSlept < seconds)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        newTimer.Dispose();

    }

    public static void newTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timeSlept = IncreaseTimerValues(ref timeSlept);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public static int IncreaseTimerValues(ref int x)
    {
        int returnThis = x + 1;
        return returnThis;
    }
```

I want the `EraseScreenLabel(Label label);` method to remove that label from the screen, such as the `GoodbyeLabel` created by the `writeTextToScreen();` method, as I don't want it to be visible anymore. How can I make that method do what I want it to? I have already tried to use `Dispose();`, and `Finalize();`, as well as `label = null;`. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: You commit several sins in this code.  Core to writing UI code is to **never** sleep.  That just doesn't work, the UI is *frozen* while you sleep and cannot redraw itself.  Creating an array with 10000000000000000000 elements is also something that can never work.  Best to work from examples or exercises in a book about .NET programming to learn the right way of writing C# code.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's much worse than that.  He's using `DoEvents()` and an unnecessary background thread to emulate `await Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
```

You just created a new empty panel.
Modifying that will have no effect on the existing panel in your form.

You need to modify the existing panel on the form.

In particular, you should get rid of your `methods` class and make those instance methods on the form class.

You should also replace `sleepFor()` with `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: I removed all of my methods from the methods class, and I created a static FlowLayoutPanel(); directly under the public int timeSlept; All of my labels now go to one central FlowLayoutPanel obj, however obj.Controls.Remove("GoodbyeLabel"); still doesn't remove that label. Did I miss part of your suggestion or what?

Comment: @ApachePilotMPE: That won't compile.